# express: How to get the client Ip instead of docker ip while use nginx as a reverse proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express, nginx

I have made a simple express server, dockerize it and use nginx as a reverse proxy. so, when I hit localhost it forwareded to the `localhost:3000`.

here is nginx config

```
server {
 server_name 103.204.85.12;
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #port where you are serving your express app.
  }
}
```

and I am sending the ip as json, I am reading the ip in this way:

```
const ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

But the problem is,
I get `172.22.0.1` when I browse into localhost:3000
I get '127.0.0.1' when I browse into nginx port (localhost)

why they are different? how can I achieve same ip (localhost instead of dockerip) ?
and when I host the app to the server I need the actual client ip instead of that dockerip.

Comment: Did you try 127.0.0.1:3000? Sometimes localhost uses the socket directly like mysql

Comment: well I hosted in on a server.
now when I visited http://45.33.97.232/ it gives me same ip
but when I visisted with port http://45.33.97.232:3000 it gives me the actual client ip

why this is happening? shouldn't actula client ip is served in both case?